# NSClassFromString @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'fetchCloudValues' compiler error

Tags: swift, objective-c

I'have a project where i have multiple targets, and in one of those targets i have added a custom class to download some Values from Firebase Remote Config.

Custom class is declared as follows:

```swift
@objc (Test)
    final class CheckUpdate: NSObject {
        @objc static let sharedInstance = CheckUpdate()
        @objc func fetchCloudValues() {
            // Grab remote config values and do things 
        }
    }
```

I've added this class as target membership only on one target and in the code I've add

```objectivec
Class asdasd = NSClassFromString(@"Test");
if (asdasd) {
   [[asdasd sharedInstance] fetchCloudValues];
}
```

My issue is that, at line where I call `fetchCloudValues` I get a compiling error saying that:

> no visible `@interface GIDSignIn` declares the selector `fetchCloudValues`

but it's obviously an issue because `asdasd` should not be of type `GIDSignIn`

Comment: Can you please paste the full compiler error, verbatim?

Comment: ARC Semantic Issue:No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'fetchCloudValues'

Comment: Is `@objc (Test)` also used with class `GIDSignIn`?

Comment: Looking into GoogleSignIn sources i'd say no